# Make the tabs active and Inactive using MVC Jquery

Tags: razor

I am trying to make tab menu active and inactive on it's click. Please take a look at below script. For eg:If I click on summary, summary tab need to get highlighted and other tabs(staff and status) need to be inactive and vice versa. I tried couple of functionalities using JQuery but it didn't work. This is MVC application and code is written in cshtml. 
Please let me know if you have any clue. Hope my question is clear. Appreciate for your help. Thanks!

Here is my script, when I click on one tab (say for eg: Summary)

```
<ul>
  <li id="liSubject"><a href="GetSubject" title="Link"><span>Summary</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="GetStaff" title="Link 2"><span>Staff</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="GetStatus" title="Link"><span>Status</span></a></li>               
</ul>
```

Comment: Give an id to anchor tag as below

        <div id="tabsI">
        <ul class="nav">
        <li id="liSubject"><a href="GetSubject" id= "aSubject" title="Link"><span>Subject</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="GetStaff" id="astaff" title="Link 2"><span>Staff</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="GetStatus" id="astatus" title="Link"><span>Status</span></a></li>               
        </ul>
       </div>
Here is your CSS 
    tabsI ul li .active {   
    width:inherit;
    background-color:#a9bee3;    
    text-decoration: underline;
    }

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".nav li a").removeClass("active");//this will remove the active  class from previously active menu item 
            $('#aSubject).addClass('active');
            $('#aSubject).removeAttr('href');
             //Staff.cshtml
              $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".nav li a").removeClass("active");//this will remove the active   class from previously active menu item 
            $('#astaff).addClass('active');
            $('#astaff).removeAttr('href');
 apply this in all pages